# LaTeX and Bibtex: command to print a single full reference from a bib file?

Tags: latex, bibtex, bibliography

I'd like to be able to print a single reference from a Bibtex .bib file anywhere in my LaTeX document—not cite it, but print the reference, exactly as it would appear in the normal bibliography listing.

So if this is a regular citation, that prints a bracketed reference:

```
% Normal citation, appears as bracketed reference, e.g. [2]
\cite{Kawahara:2007p1116}
```

I want something like the following:

```
\print_citation{Kawahara:2007p1116}
```

which should print the full citation as it appears in the bibliography, something like:

> [2] S Kawahara. Half rhymes in japanese rap lyrics and knowledge of similarity. *Journal of East Asian
> Linguistics*, Jan 2007.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

bibentry package would provide inline bibliography. Ref: http://stefaanlippens.net/bibentry.

I've not tried it out myself though.

Comment: The `bibentry` package works with the `natbib` package.  You can write `\bibentry{Kawahara:2007p1116}` and it will print the full citation (as it appears in the bibliography).

Answer (score 38):

Use `\fullcite` with the [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package as mentioned in [this answer on tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2922/30485).

Comment: Not quite. This will produce a citation with all the information that in many ways looks like a full reference, but not exactly as it would in the reference list, with a [2] identifier, as requested.

Answer (score 11):

My CV uses `multibib` nicely:

```
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}

% Define bibliographies.
\newcites{j,c}{Journal Publications,Conference Publications}

\begin{document}
% Stuff here.

% Publications.
\bibliographystylej{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystylec{IEEEtran}

\nocitej{journalpaperlabel1}
\nocitej{journalpaperlabel2}
\nocitec{conferencepaperlabel1}

\bibliographyj{mybib}
\bibliographyc{mybib}

% More stuff here.
\end{document}
```

Edited with something less self-promoting [here](http://up.stevetjoa.com/multibib.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163774/biblatex-print-bibliography-for-a-single-entry-within-an-enumeration), that provides a trick using `biblatex` and its category system:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Gyro2012,
  author = {Gearloose, Gyro},
  title = {1st paper with a very loooooooooooong title, so it spans multiple rows},
}
@misc{Gyro2013,
  author = {Gearloose, Gyro},
  title = {2nd paper},
}
@misc{Stark2012,
  author = {Stark, Anthony Edward},
  title = {3rd paper},
}
@misc{Stark2013,
  author = {Stark, Anthony Edward},
  title = {4th paper},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{enumpapers}

\newcommand{\enumcite}[1]{%
  \addtocategory{enumpapers}{#1}%
  \defbibcheck{key#1}{
    \iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{#1}
      {}
      {\skipentry}}%
  \printbibliography[heading=none,check=key#1]%
}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \enumcite{Gyro2012}
    \setcounter{enumi}{9} % Two digits to test alignment
    \item \enumcite{Gyro2013}
\end{enumerate}

\printbibliography[notcategory=enumpapers]
\end{document}
```